# How to know if the typed alphabet is uppercase in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

The keyCode returned is between 29 and 54 for alphabets which doesn't account for uppercase. I even tried the **isCapsLockOn()** method to distinguish between the uppercase and lowercase alphabets but no success.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        try {
            if (keyCode >= 29 && keyCode <= 54) {
                if (event.isCapsLockOn()) {
                    dos.writeInt(keyCode + 36);
                    dos.flush();
                }else{
                    dos.writeInt(keyCode+68);
                    dos.flush();
                }
            }else if(keyCode>=7 && keyCode<=16){
                dos.writeInt(keyCode+41);
                dos.flush();
            }
            else {
                switch (keyCode) {
                    case 62: //space
                        dos.writeInt(32);
                        break;
                    case 66:// enter
                        dos.writeInt(10);
                        break;
                    default:
                     break;
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
```

**Please tell me if there is a way to identify if the alphabet is uppercase or not !! Thanks in advance!!**

Comment: You may find this method useful: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#getUnicodeChar()

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return Character.isUpperCase(event.getKeyChar());
}
```

which will return true if the char is in uppercase.

See [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/character_isuppercase.htm) for an explanation of isUpperCase(char c) and [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyChar()) for getting the char of a KeyEvent.

Comment: Well I tried this but I got an error could not resolve getKeyChar()... Maybe android studio doesn't recognize this method...

Comment: But this helped me explore another method getUnicodeChar() and it worked.... I will definitely upvote for your help .. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

So i got to work around this by using getUnicodeChar() method. I will post my solution in case it helps someone in future.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG,"Unicode: "+event.getUnicodeChar());
            if(keyCode==67){
                dos.writeInt(8);// Special case since backspace returns unicode 0 in android
                dos.flush();
            }else if(keyCode!=59){ // Also ignoring shift key if it is pressed
                dos.writeInt(event.getUnicodeChar());
                dos.flush();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
```